# How can I update json value in oracle without APEX?

Tags: json, oracle

Can you help? How can I update json value in oracle without APEX ? 
For read I use json_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there are useful PL/SQL functions introduced in 12.2. See the developer guide [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADJSN/using-PLSQL-object-types-for-JSON.htm#ADJSN-GUID-F0561593-D0B9-44EA-9C8C-ACB6AA9474EE).

If you are not on 12.2, there is a Java API [here](https://odieweblog.wordpress.com/2015/07/30/json-update-for-the-impatient/).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using simple update statements?
If yes, then you can modify your content like this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET DOCUMENT_COLUMN = REPLACE(DOCUMENT_COLUMN, JSON_ELEMENT, NEW_VALUE);
```

Your column has to be a CLOB column and you need to define a constraint like this on your table to enforce JSON usage.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONSTRAINT tbl_json_chk CHECK (DOCUMENT_COLUMN IS JSON (STRICT))
```

Comment: I have a similar question. Can you please explain with an example?